# how to create a lag using R

Tags: r, lag

my data set looks like this

```
Xmy
-1.82145396
18.62636281
-85.33997844
4.89112308
18.67135686
-12.68065012
15.87559012
-5.63945197
2.22151353
25.95263943
15.18778398
30.97540045
```

I want to create a lag for this data set by 3 as each value corresponds to a month in ascending order. from January to december. how do i create the lag?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

## Code

```
Xmy = c(
-1.82145396,
18.62636281,
-85.33997844,
4.89112308,
18.67135686,
-12.68065012,
15.87559012,
-5.63945197,
2.22151353,
25.95263943,
15.18778398,
30.97540045)

library(Hmisc)
lag  <- Lag(Xmy, -3)
```

## Output:

```
> lag
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 12 
Frequency = 1 
 [1]   4.891123  18.671357 -12.680650  15.875590  -5.639452   2.221514  25.952639  15.187784  30.975400         NA         NA         NA
```

Comment: it says object x not found when i try to replace x with my variable Xmy it says Xmy not found.